# Q: Laravel Blade view syntax error: unexpected '<'

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have encountered a syntax error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<') in my Laravel view file. The idea is to set the 'selected' state of the `option`, depending on a certain value in the database.

Can somone help plese (I am very new to Laravel!)

Cheers

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="">
     <option disabled>Please select...</option>

   @if ( {{ $asset->country }} === 'NZ' )
     <option value="OZ">OZ</option>
     option value="NZ" selected>NZ</option>
   @endif

</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove curly brackets:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="">
   <option disabled>Please select...</option>

   @if( $asset->country === 'NZ' )
     <option value="OZ">OZ</option>
     <option value="NZ" selected>NZ</option>
   @endif

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Pavel!  So, what is the rule for {{ }} brackets in Blade - they are never used in IF statements?

Comment: Yes, curly brackets are used to display some variables, and other statements like 'if', 'isset', loops should used without brackets. You can read more on [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)